# Conditional custom menu?

Tags: functions, menus, filters, sub-menu

I'm trying to create a custom menu that displays a `<li></li>` when a user is logged in, and not display it when they're not. I have this so far, but it's not working. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','custom_nav_items',1,2);
function custom_nav_items($menu, $args) {
global $bp;
$args = (array)$args;
if ( $args['theme_location'] != 'primary' )
    return $menu;
$customNav = '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ss-nav-menu-item-5 ss-nav-menu-item-depth-0 ss-nav-menu-reg ss-nav-menu-mega-alignRight customNav"><a href="'. $bp->loggedin_user->domain .'">'. $bp->loggedin_user->fullname .'</a>
<ul class="sub-menu sub-menu-1">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ss-nav-menu-item-depth-1"><a href="'. $bp->loggedin_user->domain .'">View Profile</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ss-nav-menu-item-depth-1"><a href="'. $bp->loggedin_user->domain .'profile/edit/">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ss-nav-menu-item-depth-1"><a href="'. $bp->loggedin_user->domain .'settings/">Edit Settings</a></li>'
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ss-nav-menu-item-depth-1"><a href="'. wp_logout_url( bp_get_root_domain() ) .'">Logout</a></li>' }
'<ul>
</li>';
return $menu.$customNav;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` to connect the strings after your `is_user_logged_in()`. To be honest: Try to write cleaner code and use an IDE like PHPStorm, Aptana/Eclipse, etc. Those will show you such typos instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe a plugin would be needed for this.

You could add a class to the menu item (enable the class field under Screen Options when you are editing the menu item). Also be sure that you have the `body_class()` function applied to your body tag. Then you can do:

```
.your-menu-item-class {
    display: none;
}
.logged-in .your-menu-item-class {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available at http://wpsmith.net/my-plugins/wp-custom-menu-filter-plugin/ that has the functionality you are looking for.

You add classes to the menu items to indicate whether they are for logged in users, or unknown users.

Comment: I have used this plugin, works well, simple to use.